# ¿Cómo unificar dos campos en una consulta de SQL (phpMyAdmin)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, consultar

El día de hoy, tengo un problemilla para la creación de una tabla en SQL, ya que necesito unificar 2 campos que se repiten con la consulta que realicé, pero no encuentro la forma de realizarlo.

La consulta que se realizó, es la siguiente (esto en phpMyAdmin):

```
SELECT c.NombreCliente, mq.NombreMarca, COUNT(*) as total_equipos_marca FROM registro r 
LEFT JOIN empleados e ON r.IDEmpleado = e.IDEmpleado 
LEFT JOIN cliente c ON c.IDCliente = e.IDCliente
LEFT JOIN equipos eq ON eq.IDEquipo = r.IDEquipo
LEFT JOIN marcaequipos mq ON mq.IDMarca = eq.IDMarca
GROUP BY mq.IDMarca, c.IDCliente;
```

El resultado de esta consulta:

[image: Resultado]

Quiero obtener esos dos campos unificados, sin importar que en la columna de  `NombreMarca` y  `NombreMarca` halla más filas.

Es decir, quiero que se vea una sola vez el  `NombreCliente` independientemente de las inserciones de las columnas derechas.

Comment: Para eso tendrías que quitar a `mq.IDMarca` del `GROUP BY`, si observas, te los diferencia porque estás agrupando también por marca, y una es `DELL` y la otra `LENOVO`.

Comment: Pero en ese ejemplo, desaparecería una marca, pues ese cliente ha comprado a 2 marcas. No necesitas esos datos?

Comment: No, ya probé de esa forma y no funciona, porque me aparecería el total de los equipos, pero sin separarlos por marca

Comment: Quizá debes replantear tu lógica. No tiene sentido querer agrupar por nombre y marca al mismo tiempo.